# how to excute more than one for loop in xquery

Tags: xquery

Problem is very simple. let think I have two simple for loop in Xquery.

```
for $i in 1 to 3
return <oneEval>{$i}</oneEval>

for $j in 10 to 30
return <tenEval>{$j}</tenEval>
```

If I run individually it is fine. But if I want to run concurrently it gives error. Can't I use more one 'return' in a Xquery? Can anybody please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning it into a sequence. Wrap the entire xquery in parentheses and separate the for loops with a comma.

Example:

```
(
for $i in 1 to 3
return <oneEval>{$i}</oneEval>
,
for $j in 10 to 30
return <tenEval>{$j}</tenEval>
)
```

You can reformat the example. I kept the parens and comma on separate lines so it would be easier to see the additions.

Comment: I thought I can't write more than one return.